# More like this with nested object does not work when specifying a record

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have an elasticsearch index with a nested mapping like this :

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "esdata": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "record": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "text",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "my_index",
        "creation_date": "1502272783802",
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "stop"
              ],
              "char_filter": [
                "html_strip"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "35O9YT3eQGKhukPFbUTflw",
        "version": {
          "created": "5050199"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i execute a query with more_like_this and i specify a like text, it works correctly :

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "record",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "record.name": "Report" }},
            {"more_like_this": {
              "fields": [
                "record.value"
              ],
              "like": "some thing is wrong",
              "min_term_freq": 1,
              "max_query_terms": 12
            }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when i use the more_like_this with a specific document id, it does not work (for information, i duplicated a record, so at least i should get one result for this duplicated record)

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "record",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "record.name": "Report" }},
            {"more_like_this": {
              "fields": [
                "record.value"
              ],
              "like": [
                {
                  "_id": "2"
                }
              ],
              "min_term_freq": 1,
              "max_query_terms": 12
            }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```